# Target _blank not working when programatically clicking link

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have the following snippet in my project

```
const doDownload = (blob) => {
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            let link = document.getElementById('downloadButton');
            if (isMobile && (browserName == 'Chrome'))
                link.download == null;
            else
                link.download = getFilename();
            link.href = url;
            link.click();
        }
```

It works as intended on desktop, and on other mobile browsers.

But on Firefox iOS, when clicking the button that calls that function, the link opens in the current tab instead of a new tab.

How can I force it to open the link in a new tab?